Problema com o uso de funções genéricas e declaração explícita de tipo em tipos customizados
Estou definindo um tipo customizado que assuma o tipo number somente quando o parâmetro passado seja negativo. Para isso, defini dois tipos:
   type Negative<X extends number> = `${X}` extends `-${string}` ? X : never;
   type Negative2<X extends number> =  `${X}` extends `-${string}` ? number : never;

Embora funcionem de forma parecida, o tipo gerado, quando o parâmetro é um número negativo, por Negative é estritamente o número passado como parâmetro, enquanto o Negative2 gera a primitiva number. Quando o parâmetro é um número positivo o tipo gerado será never em ambos os casos.
O problema ocorre justamente quando tais tipos são utilizados em funções, como no exemplo:
   function isNegative<N extends number>(n: Negative<N>): number {
      return n;
   }

   function isNegative2<N extends number>(n: Negative2<N>): number {
      return n;
   }

   let r = isNegative(-10)
   let r2 = isNegative2(-10)

Nesse caso, a chamada de isNegative2 não é considerada válida, pois exige um parâmetro do tipo never, gerando um erro e impedindo a compilação, enquanto isNegative funciona normalmente, atribuindo à r o valor e tipo correto, respectivamente, -10 e number.
Outra informação útil está contida na assinatura das funções:
   function isNegative<-10>(n: -10): number
   function isNegative2<number>(n: never): number

É possível notar que o tipo genérico de N, atribuído pelo próprio typescript atráves de type argument inference, é diferente para ambas as chamadas, sendo estritamente o número para a primeira e o tipo primitivo para a segunda, apesar do parâmetro passado ser o mesmo, sendo essa, possivelmente, a causa do erro.
Testes
Modificando a chamada da função isNegative com o objetivo de forçar N a ser considerado number, é possível identificar o mesmo erro de isNegative2 :
   //assinatura: function isNegative<number>(n: never): number
   let r = isNegative<number>(-10)

   //assinatura: function isNegative2<number>(n: never): number
   let r2 = isNegative2(-10)

Esse fato é explicado pois let u: Negative<number> e let u2: Negative2<number> são declarações válidas e atribuem a u e u2 o tipo never.
Apesar disso, modificar a definição dos tipos não altera diretamente o valor atribuído à N, como por exemplo:
   type Negative2<X extends number> =  `${X}` extends `-${string}` ? -10 : never;

   function isNegative2<N extends number>(n: Negative2<N>): number {
      return n;
   }

   //assinatura: function isNegative2<number>(n: never): number
   //não se modifica mesmo após a troca do tipo number para o tipo -10 
   let r2 = isNegative2(-10)

Pergunta
Com esse resultado e baseado na documentação, que indica que o tipo passado como parâmetro será atribuído ao tipo genérico, gostaria de entender a razão por trás desse comportamento nessa função, onde a declaração explicita do tipo alterou a atribuição do tipo genérico.

Me ajude a entender o que você quer saber. Porque me parece que vocês está tentando usando o sistema de introspecção de tipos para computar valores? Deixa eu explicar porque estou perguntando: se você fizer por exemplo let r = isNegative(25) em client side o código do navegador é interrompido, será lançado um erro, uma mensagem será impressa no console e próximo evento talvez o código retome e a vida que segue.

Agora, se fizer let r = isNegative(25) em server side a história é outra, o código do servidor será interrompido e finalizado, serão gerados logs de interrupção de processo, todos o clientes serão desconectados ao mesmo tempo, sua aplicação ficará fora do ar e só voltará a funcionar com intervenção manual e toda a vez que o servidor chegar noamente a linha let r = isNegative(25) essa cascata nefasta de evento irá acontecer. E todo esse ciclo pode ser evitado com um código do tipo if(x<0) {faça isso} else {faça aquilo}.

Meu objetivo é entender como a declaração explicita do tipo na definição  de Negative2 alterou a atribuição do tipo genérico na função. Fiz algumas modificações na pergunta para deixar mais claro, tanto os testes que já fiz, quanto minha dúvida. Quanto ao uso desse código, ela está em um projeto offline e é utilizado como uma forma de assert. Apesar da condicional resolver mais facilmente o problema, estou muito interessado na explicação desse comportamento.

Na realidade, se jogar no javascript, ambos os seus códigos vão funcionar, tanto o Negative e o Negative2 eles vão retornar -10. É, o javascript tem dessas.
O grande porém é, como a IDE dá uma verificada nos argumentos do Typescript antes, ela pode realmente acusar o retorno do never e impossibilitar a execução.
Isso aí acontece porque no caso de Negative2, a tipagem vai fazer ele retornar um tipo mais abrangente, com estrutura maior que o tipo suportado, que é um number, diferente do Negative que retorna de fato um tipo específico, que ele suporta.
Para exemplificar melhor, se considerar um terceiro caso, o Negative3:
type Negative3<X extends number> = `${X}` extends `-${string}` ? Negative<X> : never;

E a função:
function isNegative3<N extends number>(n: Negative3<N>): number {
  return n;
}

Se você rodar isso:
let r3 = isNegative3(-10)

Ele vai aceitar.
Mas por que?
Porque o Negative3 é filho de number, porém, ao invés de ele retornar o pai, como no Negative2, ele está retornando um outro filho de number também que é o Negative, ou seja, é um tipo compatível e possível.
Quando o tipo não é compatível, ele sempre vai retornar never (neste caso é um nunca).
